# How do I keep a variable passed via URL for multiple form submits?

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a variable being passed to a web page called ID via a URL (i.e. ?id=33).  This is then used to update a record when a form is submitted.  Should the user press SUBMIT again (or multiple times) I would like their record to take the latest data from the form, allowing the user to correct a mistake.
However, I cannot seem to keep the variable $id alive.  When SUBMIT is pressed a second time the $id variable no longer holds its value.

Comment: Use a session variable.

Comment: "Should"? Is this a [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) question, or an opinionated one? Also, sessions were made for a reason. Storing it on the form would make your site extremely vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Ordinary variables are reset every time the form runs.

Comment: @Spectric "Should" means "When" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a session variable , this will keep the variable alive as long as you want.
But the variable is destroyed when you close your browser or destroy the session.

For example:

```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
```

To destroy a session:

```
   session_destroy();
   $_SESSION=array();
```